# Why would this code (deleting several items at once) hang up behind firewall?

Tags: javascript, ajax

It works all the time except when behind a firewall. In this case it gives a timeout error in debugger, no error messages otherwise. Why would this happen? Do I need to make this code more efficient by creating an object in memory?

```
function deleteEntries() {      
var ids = getCheckedIds();

    if(ids.length >= 1) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "/mainview/delete_selected.js",
    data: {ids: ids, date: $("#calendar").val()},
    dataType: "script"
  });

}
```

No problem with deleting items one by one.

Comment: It’s probably because you send a DELETE request or a request containing `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bypass this you should use the X-HTTP-Method-Override header to specify the http method

Comment: Assuming the server understands this header.-

Answer (score 1):

Some firewalls block HTTP DELETE.  You could prove this by sending the raw HTTP message from a simple client, you could use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to do this.  If the firewall is blocking DELETE then they are performing deep inspection on the network traffic.  This could be resolved by either:

1. Allowing the connection through firewall configuration (if you have control of the firewall)
2. Using HTTPS which prevents the firewall from inspecting the traffic.
3. Use a different Verb

Comment: Thanks, Fiddler was helpful. I do not have control over the firewall, though, so had to use the other answer